# How do I change the FileVault login icon on OSX Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, filevault

I'd like to change the apple on the FileVault login screen to something else. I've searched Google, but none of the links I've found have worked. They all suggest changing one or more of the following, none of which seems to work:

- `/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Resources/NSTexturedFullScreenBackgroundColor.png`
- `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Resources/apple.png`
- `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Resources/appleLinen.png`

I've changed those, but the apple remains on the FileVault login screen. As [Daniel Beck](https://superuser.com/users/22317/daniel-beck) points out, that's because those files are on the encrypted disk, and thus couldn't possibly be what FileVault is using to show the login screen.

Comment: Changing that last image worked for me. I opened it in Preview, flipped it horizontally, saved it on the Desktop, and replaced that file using my version from the command line. Now I have a left-facing Apple.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are referring to: The *Login Window* (where you're entering your password), the *Boot Image* (when nothing else but the Apple is displayed), or maybe even the *EFI-based Login Window for File Vault 2*?

Comment: I can't get a screenshot, but I suspect it's the file vault screen. It's a solid grey screen with an apple of a different grey.

Comment: @dan there is indeed. And the background is definitely NOT patterned as I see in many screenshots.

Comment: Great point on the encrypted data problem. When I first asked the question, I didn't realize I was looking at the FileVault screen.

Answer (score 3):

Since the hard drive is encrypted, the login screen cannot show these files directly before you unlock the drive by logging in. If you activate File Vault, certain resources, like the Apple icon, are placed on the *Recovery HD* partition for presenting them.

These resources are recreated every time you change a setting affecting the boot login screen, e.g.

- *System Preferences » Users & Groups » Login Options » Display login window as…*
- *System Preferences » Security & Privacy » Disable restarting to Safari when screen is logged* (i.e. "Safari guest account")

Change the files you know already to the desired resource, and toggle one of these options to recreate the resources on your boot disk.

You can test correct presentation by activating *Fast user switching menu* in *Login Options* of *Users & Groups* preference pane, and selecting *Login Window…* from the new menu item.

---

Alternatively, you can edit the `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.corestorage/EFILoginLocalizations/loginui.efires` file in the *Recovery HD* partition's rock-paper-scissors `com.apple.boot.X` folder manually using the information [in this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/364593/what-are-the-efires-files-on-os-x-lions-recovery-hd). The Apple icon is the entry named `loginui_apple.png`.

Be aware that your changes will be overridden whenever you change a relevant setting in *System Preferences*.

Comment: Unfortunately changing options in system preferences does not seem to work in Big Sur. Wallpaper on filevault login screen does not change no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

[BootXChanger](http://namedfork.net/bootxchanger) might be what you need. It has instructions on the download page.

> BootXChanger will allow you to change the boot image and background
>   colour on Mac OS X 10.4, 10.5 and 10.6
>
> To set an image as a boot image, open BootXChanger and drag it to the
>   image well, and click Apply. You can also click the background colour
>   to change it. You will then be asked for an administrator password, as
>   the boot image is stored in a system file.

[image]

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't seem to support Lion.

Answer (score 0):

When you have trouble getting it onto the Recovery partition, you can just use the workaround identified in this blog post:

http://zephauniah.com/2013/02/11/how-to-change-the-apple-logo-on-your-macs-login-screen-with-filevault-2-enabled/

Comment: Can you please [provide a context for that link](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)? This helps future readers if that blog post were to become unavailable.