# Where does OS X Lion store the round user icon frame picture?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

What is the location of the round silver frame picture around the user icon that appears on the login screen?
I want to find and change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ring around the user image and the glossy overlay is the following file:

> `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/avatarWhiteRing.png`

The mask for the regular user image is the following file:

> `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/avatarMask.png`

Comment: If you use File Vault 2, it is much more difficult to change the resources for *that* login window. You are actually booting from the recovery partition. I suggest you keep your hands off that login screen's resources.

Comment: Thank You! :)  
Daniel, I will be careful but it is manifestly important to change it! :D

Comment: @ValKalinic I'm still working on changing the FV2 login screen. [Another related question](http://superuser.com/questions/362788/how-do-i-change-the-filevault-login-icon-on-osx-lion) contains the tiny bit of information I was able to figure out so far.

Comment: @ValKalinic Figured it out. See the other topic — it's not as difficult as I thought.