# What are the .efires files on OS X Lion's Recovery HD?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, file-format, filevault, efi

If you mount the *Recovery HD* that enables OS X Lion File Vault 2, Safari mode, and certain recovery options, you see several `.efires` files. What format are those and what do they contain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These files contain resources required for displaying the boot screen of OS X Lion before loading the actual operating system or in cases there is no system partition (or when it's broken).

They contain a flat list of files (no hierarchy), and each file has a name of up to 64 characters. The file format is as follows; all numbers are *little endian*, i.e. least significant byte first.

- Two bytes `0x0200` with unknown purpose
- Two byte short integer with the number of file entries (e.g. `0x3800` is 56 files)
- Now there will be one record for every file entry:

  - 64 bytes ASCII file name, with `NUL` bytes used to fill up
  - 4 byte integer *offset* of the file data within the archive file
  - 4 byte integer *length* of the file data within the archive file
- There is an additional unused record after the file entries consisting of 72 `NUL` bytes.
- Now there is the actual file data. There are no gaps or separators, the file entries described above position the data of all files right next to each other.

The first file's data offset in e.g. an archive file with 56 entries is `0x0C10`, or 4108 bytes, by default:

**2** bytes unknown + **2** bytes file count + (**56+1** file entries) *** 72** bytes each **= 4108**.

The second file's data offset in the same file is 4108 plus the length of the first file's data.

---

These files are recreated automatically whenever you change a setting relevant for the boot login screen, e.g. whether to enable Safari mode in *Security & Privacy* preference pane in *System Preferences*). It uses default system resources to do this, so if you want to change e.g. [the Apple icon](https://superuser.com/questions/362788/how-do-i-change-the-filevault-login-icon-on-osx-lion), it is sufficient to edit the regular resource and have the system recreate the corresponding `.efires` archive file.

Comment: Very interesting; thanks for posting your research!

Comment: @Gordon Thanks. Too bad it's not that important -- didn't figure out the last paragraph until I was finished writing a tool to generate these files ;)

Comment: @Daniel Beck you should release the source for your tool :c

Comment: [Here's a small tool to unpack/pack these files I wrote](https://gist.github.com/stek29/d13a34229a09020e0c1b0d897c42b433)